# How to "take custody" of a variable for the lifetime of a struct?

Tags: rust, struct, lifetime

This compiles and passes the test:

```
use std::io::Write;

/*
 * This transforms a writer into a writer where every write is prefixed
 * with a timestamp and terminated with a newline.
 */

struct Timestamper<T: Write> {
    writer: T,
}

impl<T: Write> Timestamper<T> {
    pub fn new(writer: T) -> Timestamper<T> {
        Timestamper { writer }
    }
    pub fn drop(self) -> T {
        self.writer
    }
}

impl<T: Write> Write for Timestamper<T> {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        self.writer.write(b"timestamp ")?;
        let expected_size = self.writer.write(buf)?;
        self.writer.write(b"\n")?;
        std::io::Result::Ok(expected_size)
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        self.writer.flush()
    }
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::io::Write;
    use super::Timestamper;

    #[test]
    fn test_timestamper() {
        let buf = Vec::new(); // buffer to write into
        let mut timestamper = Timestamper::new(buf);
        let hello_len = timestamper.write(b"hello").unwrap();
        let world_len = timestamper.write(b"world").unwrap();
        assert_eq!(hello_len, 5);
        assert_eq!(world_len, 5);
        let buf2 = timestamper.drop();
        assert_eq!(buf2.as_slice(), b"timestamp hello\ntimestamp world\n");
    }
}
```

Is making a `drop()` method, which returns the `writer` object, idiomatic in Rust?

Is `drop()` the correct name for a final unwrapping function?

Comment: The `drop()` method is usually `Drop::drop()`. The common name for what you are doing here is `into_inner()`.

Comment: As Sven points out, `into_inner()` is the obvious choice, at least when it's clear what "inner" refers to. You can also use `into_writer()` to make it a bit more explicit. (The prefix "into_" communicates that the method is consuming `self`.)

Comment: Not directly related to  your issue but I'd expect a timestamper to insert the timestamp after every line break in the input, not after every write call. That way it will create readable output even when using functions like `fprintln!()` that map to multiple write calls

Comment: @mousetail For the general case, yes, you're absolutely correct.  In my very specific circumstances, I know that every write is going to be a whole unterminated line and so I can create some (documented) technical debt and keep moving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common approach in Rust, but you shouldn't call the method `drop()`. The `Drop::drop()` mehtod has different semantics. The common name for a [method returning the wrapped value is `into_inner()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html?search=into_inner).

Depending on your use case, you could also pass a mutable reference to a writer into the wrapper. Mutable references to an object implementing `Write` also implement `Write`, so this will work without any further code. The advantage of using a borrow is that you don't need to do anything to get the original writer back. Once the borrow ends, you can immediately use the original value again. The downside is that you can't unwrap the wrapped writer in a different context than where you created the struct.